# AWK is printing all columns

Tags: awk

I want to isolate the second column.

If I do:

```
echo "1  2 3" | awk "{ print $2 }"
```

the result is:

```
1  2 3
```

The expected result is:

```
2
```

I've tried with `-F' '` option, but the result is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need single quotes:

`echo "1  2 3" | awk '{ print $2 }'`

will return `2`

Comment: Thank you! I was getting crazy!

Answer (score 1):

#### What am I doing wrong?

> ```
> echo "1  2 3" | awk "{ print $2 }"
> ```

The correct command is

```
echo "1  2 3" | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Or

```
echo "1  2 3" | awk "{ print \$2 }"
```

Example:

```
$ echo "1  2 3" | awk '{ print $2 }'
2
$ echo "1  2 3" | awk "{ print \$2 }"
2
```

Comment: No; `awk` uses double quotes in its own scripts, but this is irrelevant here. Before `awk` starts running, the _shell_ sees the double quotes and substitutes the value of whatever **it** knows as "$2", so `awk` runs with argument `{ print 1 2 3 }`, which it obediently does.

Comment: I'm referring to the awk pattern/commands which **does** use single quotes.

Comment: tzot is right. If you use double quotes, you have to escape the $ to prevent the shell from substituting it. echo "1  2 3" | awk "{ print \$2 }". Awk will never know what kind of quotes were used. It gets the string w/o the quotes.

Comment: @ruud Ah. OK....

Comment: @tzot Yes, inside double quotes we must escape the `$` in the shell context; that's right. However, in this specific case, the shell interprets `$2` as blank: `echo "1  2 3" | echo "[$2]"` prints `[]`, and the `awk` runs `"{ print  }"`, which will print the entire argument as it is.

Comment: @SonySantos yes, you are absolutely correct! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A correct approach has been already given in two other answers:

```
echo "1  2 3" | awk '{print $2}'
```

The "why", though, was lacking, so I am adding it.

```
echo "1  2 3" | awk "{print $2}"
```

fails because shells perform **parameter expansion** on `$2`. I.e., it retrieves the value of that variable, just as `a=6;echo "$a"` prints 6 in the command-line. From the [POSIX shell manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03),

> Enclosing characters in double-quotes ( "" ) shall preserve the literal value of all characters within the double-quotes, **with the exception of** the characters backquote (`), **dollar-sign ($)**, and backslash (\).

Unless your shell was started with arguments (highly unlikely scenario), `$2` expands to the null string and awk never sees `$2`, just `{print }`, thus printing the whole `1  2 3` string.

Bear in mind that it is false to say that the awk program *must* be enclosed in single-quotes. Awk just needs to get its bytes and could not care less about what steps the shell takes to deliver them. So, these are also correct:

```
echo "X  Y Z" | awk "{print \$2}"
```

```
echo "X  Y Z" | awk \{print\ \$2\}
```

Yikes! I said it was correct, not clean.

Conclusion: Surround the awk program in single-quotes whenever possible.